# Kibana not sending alert on new data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I have an Alert setup on Kibana (v7.1.1) for sending an alert whenever an OutOfMemory log is encountered. The trigger is setup with severity 2 to send alert to a list of email with `Throttle actions to only trigger every 5mins`. This alert creates a trigger after 10 mins from the creation time and keeps sending alert until I click `Acknowledge` it. Once I click `Acknowledge` the trigger is not generated ever again even though OOM logs are being generated.

I want this to send alert whenever a new OOM log is encountered and stop for next 5 mins (by enabling throttling) if OOM logs still keep generating. Following are the monitor details:

*Monitor Name*: OOM Alert

*Schedule*: By interval every 5mins

*Define Monitor*: Define using extraction query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "from": "{{period_end}}||-1d",
                            "to": "{{period_end}}",
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "log": {
                            "wildcard": "*outofmemory*",
                            "rewrite": "constant_score",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably when you are acknowledging it. Its ignoring other similar alerts.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to change the date filter to this:

```
   "range": {
              "@timestamp": {
                "gte": "now-16h",
                "lt": "now"}}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code and how it will make a difference.

Comment: can you try to replace ` "@timestamp": {` block in your query with the suggested ?